# Method not dividing for desired double value

Tags: java, double, division

In my program, I'm trying to divide two double values and return the quotient of it. Like this:

```
public double getMonthlyPayment(){
    double monthlyRate = AnnualInterestRate / 1200;
    double numberOfMonths = numberOfYears * 12;

    double dividend = (loanAmount * monthlyRate);
    double divisor = (1 - Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -numberOfMonths));

    return dividend / divisor;
}
```

Currently it's not returning the value I'm expecting. It's only returning the dividend value and not the value when dividend is divided by divisor.

For example, since this is a loan calculator, I need a loan of $2000 with 5% interest for 2 years. In order to achieve this value, you would need to use a certain equation.

I've made my own form of that equation in the code above and it's only returning the dividend value, which is `(loanAmount * monthlyRate)`, instead of returning dividend value divided by `(1 - Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -numberOfMonths))`

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try to replace `1`s by `1.0` and `1200` by `1200.0` to make those numbers be treated as doubles.

Comment: Perhaps `Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -numberOfMonths)` is so small that `1-Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -numberOfMonths)` returns `1.0`, due to the limited precision.

Comment: Could you post the complete program (including the values that you set `loanAmount`, `numberOfMonths`, and `AnnualInterestRate` to?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show, but if `AnnualInterestRate` is an `int`, then the division by `1200` is done using integer logic, and the result (an integer) is *then* coerced to `double`. Specifying `1200.0` will force coercion of `AnnualInterestRate` to `double` *before* the division.

Comment: Yes, this is right.  I tried the code when a different poster posted the same code in a question; but when I added `AnnualInterestRate`, I declared it as a `double` without thinking too hard, and the program produced the correct result.  On the other hand, this means that `dividend` would always be 0, which I'd think the questioner would have mentioned if this were the case.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know data types of all variables in your question. If the data type of right side is integer and left side is double, explicitly cast the result to double

Correct code should be:

```
public double getMonthlyPayment(){
    double monthlyRate = (double)AnnualInterestRate / 1200;
    double numberOfMonths = (double) numberOfYears * 12;

    double dividend = (loanAmount * monthlyRate);// Assuming loanAmount is double
    double divisor = (1 - Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -numberOfMonths));

    return dividend / divisor;
}
```

Comment: don't cast to `double` *after* doing the calculation. Do it *before*.